# Sharepoint Communications Site and mailto email link

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to add a mailto link to my communication site within SharePoint. I have looked extensively on the web, but found no help in this area relating to a communication site. I see for other types of SharePoint sites it's possible. I think we are using SharePoint 2016. Is it possible to add a mailto link to a communication site within SharePoint?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Late but for anyone else add mailto: followed by the email address to a link in a text web part...

mailto:it-helpdesk@somewhere.com